# How to disable submit button and adds loading animation on submission in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need to know how to prevent users from submit the form multiple times and disable the submit button after it's clicked in ASP.NET. Is it possible to add a loading animation after the button is disabled? I tried OnClientClick event to disable button but cancel the OnClick event that the page just post back without any changes. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(), "ServerForm",
        "if(this.submitted) return false; this.submitted = true;");
    button.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("this.value='wait...';
        this.disabled=true; {0}", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference
        (button, string.Empty)));
}
```

Comment: Tested. This is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I've used in the past is to create a new subclass of the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button that uses Javascript to disable itself after it's been clicked. Note that you have to be careful to not overwrite the ASP.NET client-side validation code.

If you want to add a loading animation after the click, you can add client-side javascript to show a previously-hidden animation icon by tweaking `validateAndDisableScript` below.

```
//
// This is a Button-derived class that will disable itself when it is clicked,
// preventing multiple submits of forms where necessary.
//
public class OneShotButton : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
{
    //
    // Javascript that invokes client validation (if enabled), and disables
    // the containing HTML element.  This script doesn't do the postback, so
    // that code has to be appended during OnPreRender.
    //
    private const string validateAndDisableScript =
        @"if ( typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function' )" +
        @"{" +
        @"  if ( !Page_ClientValidate() ) { return false; }" +
        @"}" +
        @"this.disabled = true;";   // postback code follows


    //
    // Override OnPreRender to set Javascript associated with the onclick
    // event for this button.  Most of the Javascript is prebuilt, but we
    // have to dynamically generate the postback code.
    //
    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string onClick = string.Format("{0}{1};",
            validateAndDisableScript,
            Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty) 
            );

        Attributes.Add("onclick", onClick);

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need _endRequest, _beginRequest Handlers. In code behind add this.

```
public object endRequestHandle { get; set; }

public object beginRequestHandle { get; set; }
```

In your aspx page, add this:

```
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
//Function gets called before Ajax request
            function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
                $('#SubmitButton').attr("disabled", true);
                $('#LoadingImage').css("visibility","visible");
            }
    //Function gets called after Ajax request completes
            function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
              $('#SubmitButton').attr("enabled", true);
                $('#LoadingImage').css("visibility","invisible");
            }
```